# remove special characters in redshift

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, txt

Below are the special characters in Redshift, the input data doesn't have those special characters, how can i remove or prevent them from showing?
there are small circles in the ProductEmail column data

[image]

Comment: Please avoid posting [images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) of data, sample data should be *consumable text* in your question, ideally as *create* and *insert* statements, or alternatively a [DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/). See the [question guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: It seems that the encoding of your source data is different from the encoding of your table and or your visualization tool

Comment: You say that "the input data doesn't have those special characters", but those characters are coming from _somewhere_. I suggest you look more closely at your source file -- it might be in UTF8 format. Those might be copyright symbols, since I found this on the web: `LexisNexis® Account Center`.